# Search in string for 2 of the same characters after each other

Tags: mysql

I need to search for a name where the second and third character are oo. And the lastname isn't Tomeloos.

I came up with this query

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE INSTR(naam, 'o') = 2 AND INSTR(naam, 'o') = 3
AND naam NOT LIKE '%Tomeloos';
```

But like expected this doesnt work because this part will never return true:

```
AND INSTR(naam, 'o') = 3
```

Because it will see an o at the second position.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this with the `INSTR` function?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE SUBSTR(naam, 2, 2) = 'oo'
AND naam NOT LIKE '%Tomeloos';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with `substr`

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE INSTR(naam, 'o') = 2 AND instr(substr(naam,instr(naam,'o')+1),'o')+instr(naam,'o') = 3
AND naam NOT LIKE '%Tomeloos';
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But the other answers are way more elegant. And more readable.

Answer (score 1):

While in certain flavours of SQL `INSTR` allows specifying a start position, this isn't the case for MySQL. As such, this isn't possible with `INSTR` without first getting a substring that doesn't include the 'o' in position 2.

That said, `LIKE` seems a much better fit for what you're trying to achieve:

```
WHERE naam LIKE '_oo%'
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but the answer posted by PaulF is what im looking for. Therefore i did up vote your answer.